# python pycurl giving for soap error of gnutls

Tags: python, soap, curl

While trying pycurl for some url

```
 def call_soap_curl(ncServerURL, xml, action):

  c = pycurl.Curl()
  c.setopt(pycurl.URL, ncServerURL)
  c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
  c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
  c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
  header=["Content-type: text/xml","SOAPAction:"+action,'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8','Content-Length: '+str(len(xml))]
  print header
  c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, header)
  c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, str(xml))
  import StringIO
  b = StringIO.StringIO()
  c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
  c.perform()
  ncServerData = b.getvalue()
  return ncServerData
```

The error m getting is

```
(56, 'GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.')
  @c.perform()
```

Please suggest what can be problem , how can i solve this.
**Using Ubuntu and same url in curl in php working**

This is my

```
 pycurl.version_info()
(3, '7.21.6', 464134, 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu', 17981, 'GnuTLS/2.10.5', 0, '1.2.3.4', ('dict', 'file', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'gopher', 'http', 'https', 'imap', 'imaps', 'ldap', 'pop3', 'pop3s', 'rtmp', 'rtsp', 'smtp', 'smtps', 'telnet', 'tftp'), None, 0, '1.22')
```

Comment: done it by following this http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515200 , if any other solution pls suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with libcurl compiled with GnuTLS.

Elsewhere I read:

*https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/626023/comments/28 was also
suggested, "The only way i managed to get rid of that error, was by
recompiling libcurl with OpenSSL instead of GnuTLS and then
recompiling python-pycurl against the new cURL library*

I recompiled libcurl with OpenSSL as suggested and the problem was solved for me.  I've included my recipe here for inspiration, though it's Ubuntu specific.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.26.0.tar.gz
wget http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf curl-7.26.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.26.0/
./configure --with-ssl
make
sudo make install
cd ../pycurl-7.19.0/
sudo python setup.py install

sudo ldconfig
```